# Please identify this equation: $\nabla^2 \mathbf F -k^2 \mathbf F = \mathbf A$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

Is this equation

$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf F -k^2 \mathbf F = \mathbf A
$$

somehow named? **F** and **A** are vector fields. I guess inhomogeneous sign reversed Helmholtz equation isn't appropriate ...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screened_Poisson_equation

Comment: I have no clue how did I miss that page! Thank you, Sir!